# Export a variable that is unique only first time it is referenced

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js, browserstack

Some context, I am trying to create a global variable that is set once using `Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);` or similar however whenever referenced again does not generate a new random string but returns the already generated random string.

However within parallel.conf.js and then in runner.js I have two different strings.
I have tried the logic of if `localIdentifier` is `undefined` generate a random string and if not return the already generated string by referencing where it has been inserted.

I have added the configuration I have setup relating to nightwatch + browserstack for context but don't think it should matter.
If unclear do let me know and I can provide more context.

```
parallel.conf.js

let localIdentifier;

let defineLocalIdentifier = (function(){
    if (localIdentifier === 'undefined') {
        localIdentifier = nightwatch_config.common_capabilities["browserstack.localIdentifier"];
        return localIdentifier;
    } else {
        localIdentifier = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
        return localIdentifier;
    }
})();

nightwatch_config = {
common_capabilities: {
        'browserstack.user': <user>,
        'browserstack.key': <key>,
        'browserstack.tunnel': true,
        'browserstack.localIdentifier': defineLocalIdentifier,
        'browserstack.local': true,
        'name': 'Bstack-[Nightwatch] Parallel Test',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
    }

module.exports = nightwatch_config;
module.exports.bs = {
    localIdentifier : defineLocalIdentifier
}
```

```
runner.js

const nightwatchConfig = require('./parallel.conf').bs.localIdentifier;

function BrowserStack () {
const browserStackArgs = {
            key: apiKey,
            'force': 'true',
            'forceLocal': 'true',
            'verbose': 'true',
            'localIdentifier': nightwatchConfig
        };
```

Comment: There's a lot of redundant logic here, to be honest. The fact is Node caches `require` results, so there should be no need of checking that value like you did; and this check (if you copied it as is) is wrong anyway, as `undefined !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Could you add to the code the exact ways of checking the `localIdentifier` values? Answering the direct question, `module.exports = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);` should be enough I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried console logging inside the else statement to see if you are reaching that point at least? why is defineLocalIdentifier a self invoked function?